# Unable to render <input> element with ng-model in Angular-Datatables

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

### parsing error with angularjs 1.6.9

I am using angularjs datatables and trying to include a ng-model directive in the rendered row like so:

```
vm.dtColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null)
        .withTitle('')
        .notSortable()
        .withOption('width', '5%')
        .renderWith(function (data, type, full, meta) {
            var html = '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.selected[' + data._id + ']"/>';
            console.log(html);
            return html;
        }),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('number')
        .withTitle('Number')
        .withOption('width', '35%'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('name')
        .withTitle('Name')
        .withOption('width', '50%'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('revisionNumber')
        .withTitle('Revision')
        .withOption('width', '10%')
];
```

What I am getting is a parsing exception like this:

```
Syntax Error: Token 'a4e90d73bb003d8a9d52b6f' is unexpected, expecting []] at column 14 of the expression [vm.selected[5a4e90d73bb003d8a9d52b6f]] starting at [a4e90d73bb003d8a9d52b6f]].
```

That html line is evaluating to this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.selected[5a4e90d73bb003d8a9d52b6f]"/>
```

I don't follow. It looks ok to me. How can i fix it?

Follow up to below answer:

after I used the suggested solution:

```
return '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.selected[data._id]"/>';
```

My DOM would look like this:

[image]

That makes all values be assigned to the same variable. Right?

Comment: When asking questions it is a good idea to provide a [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) which reproduces your problem. This greatly increases the possibility for others to debug your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string produced by `data._id` needs to be enclosed in quotes inside the property accessor:

```
vm.dtColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null)
        .withTitle('')
        .notSortable()
        .withOption('width', '5%')
        .renderWith(function (data, type, full, meta) {
            var accessor = "['" + data._id + "']";
            var directive = 'ng-model="selected' + accessor + '"';
            var html = '<input type="checkbox" ' + directve + ' />';
            console.log(html);
            return html;
        }),
```

This will evaluate to:

```
 ̶ ̶<̶i̶n̶p̶u̶t̶ ̶t̶y̶p̶e̶=̶"̶c̶h̶e̶c̶k̶b̶o̶x̶"̶ ̶n̶g̶-̶m̶o̶d̶e̶l̶=̶"̶v̶m̶.̶s̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶e̶d̶[̶5̶a̶4̶e̶9̶0̶d̶7̶3̶b̶b̶0̶0̶3̶d̶8̶a̶9̶d̶5̶2̶b̶6̶f̶]̶"̶/̶>̶

  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.selected['5a4e90d73bb003d8a9d52b6f']"/>
```

This assumes that `vm.selected` is initialized as an object.

Comment: Correct! Thank you.